# IBM HTTP Server, routing calls to Websphere

Tags: http, ssl, websphere

Something I have been struggling with for a while, but I'm not able to come up with a proper solution.

This is the situation:

Host 1 - IBM HTTP Server, Customization Toolbox and WAS Plugins
Host 2 - WAS + Application

These are the steps I executed to configure the plugin and propagate it from Websphere:
1. I used the Customization Toolbox, selected the correct WAS Plugins directory and created a new Web Server Plugin
2. I copied the new configureSERVER.bat to my Application Server on Host 2, and configured the current profile.
3. On Host 1, I created an Administrator account.

When I open the WAS-console on Host 2, I can see the actual Web Server, so that went ok.  When I select "Generate plugin" and "Propagate Plugin", I get no errors.  I checked the HTTP Server, and indeed, my plugin-cfg.xml is neatly created and exists.

To make sure everything is all right, I opened the `http://HOST1/snoop` on Host 1 and I saw the correct diagnostics.  So far, so good.

After that, I deployed my application, which runs on port 9044.  However, this application runs on HTTPS, so we need to make sure that the IBM HTTP Server accepts SSL connections.  I generated my own selfsigned certificate, imported it in the httpd.conf and restarted the server.  (If someone is interested, I'll put some more details on how to do this).

Now, when I open `https://HOST1/snoop` I can see the diagnostics, which is good news.  It means it accepts connections on https and reroutes it to Host 2. But the problem is, I have no idea how to access my application, which is running on port 9044.

Something that puzzles me is the details when I run the snoop-servlet.

When I run it via http (so without SSL), this is the output:

Local address   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Local host  XXXXXXXXXX
Local port  9080

That is correct, because the port on Websphere is 9080 for that particular servlet.  However, when I open `https://HOST1/snoop` (so, via SSL), this is what being generated:

Local address   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Local host  XXXXXXXXXX
Local port  9044

So, apparently, 443 is being rerouted to 9044 on the second host, but the Snoop servlet runs on 9443, not 9044 (which is my application).  But, then I wonder, why can I access the servlet, if it is running on another port.

So, if there's anyone who can give me some guidance, that would be nice.

This is the VHOST:

```
<VirtualHostGroup Name="default_host">
    <VirtualHost Name="*:9080"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:80"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:9443"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:5060"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:5061"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:443"/>
    <VirtualHost Name="*:9044"/>
</VirtualHostGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have 1 application server or 2? I'm confused as to why you have two HTTPS transports in the same virtual host, but you think your app is only associated with one of them.  

Also, You never said what happened when you acccessed your own context root over SSL to the webserver.

Comment: What do you mean with "Two HTTPS transports in the same virtual host".  It's the first time I'm doing something like this.   

There's 1 application server, not 2.  So Host 1 contains 1 HTTP Server and Host 2 contains Websphere (application server).

Comment: Well normally when you add a second application it just runs on the same ports as any previous application, mapped to the same "default_host" virtualhost, but under a new context root.  Somehow you've made it more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Event though you have 2 ports (I'm assuming you created custom transport chain and assign 9044 port to it), you added that port to `default_host`, which is visible in the `VirtualHostGroup` in the plugin. Your application is probably mapped also to the `default_host`, so it is available using all ports - 9080, 9443 and 9044. Second transport should be visible in the plugin config for your server with port 9044. Since it is also ssl transport plugin could choose that one to route request to your server. There is no way to force plugin to use specific port for communication to WAS for given application.

However you didn't specify what you actually want to achieve? Since your app should now be available via https.

Comment: What I want to achieve is the following:
Go to https://HOST1/app and arrive on https://HOST2:9044/app.  Also, could you elaborate a bit more on the rest of your post?

Comment: The application is only available on port 9044 btw, not on the other ones.

Comment: @user1905189 Then remove from plugin-cfg.xml transport related to 9443, and you will be sure that 9044 is used. Plugin uses one SSL transport and one HTTP transport for all apps.

Comment: @user1905189 Did you created separate virtual host for 9044?